# Formatear salida de texto cortándolo de un archivo en bash

Tags: bash

Perdonad si el título no queda demasiado claro, no sabía qué poner.

Tengo un fichero txt en el que se almacena información de "contactos" de la siguiente forma:
`juan:742901829:20` que viene a referirse a `nombre:teléfono:edad` en ese txt tendré un número x de filas con datos de cliente de la forma anteriormente dicha.

Ahora bien, debo coger fila a fila la información y presentarla así:

```sh
***********************
Nombre:   Juan
Teléfono: 742901829
edad:     20
***********************
```

He buscado por internet y encontré cómo hacerlo, pero no termino de enteder qué es lo que está haciendo el código y me gustaría pediros si me lo podéis explicar y si veis bien la solucion o creéis que hay alguna mejor o simplemente otra, cuantas más formas sepa de hacer algo, mejor.

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```sh
function show ()
{
    if [ -f ./Agenda.txt ] # Se comprueba si existe el directorio.
    then
        for LINE in $(cat ./Agenda.txt)
        do
            local NAME=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 1)
            local PHONE=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 2)
            local AGE=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 3)

            echo ""
            echo "************************************"
            echo -e "Nombre:   ${NAME} \nTeléfono: ${PHONE} \nEdad:     ${AGE}" 
            echo "************************************"

        done
    else
        echo "No existe el directorio"
    fi
}
```

Sobre todo, esta parte `local NAME=$(echo $LINE | cut -d ":" -f 1)` no entiendo por qué la necesidad de usar echo.

Gracias.

Comment: el script en sí funciona pero el código es muy mejorable. No sé si contemplas buscar una alternativa más limpia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede hacer en una sola línea con `awk`:

```
awk -F : '{
printf "*******************************\nNombre: %s\nTeléfono: %s\nEdad: %s\n*******************************\n", 
$1, $2, $3
}' Agenda.txt
```

Tomo como separador los dos puntos ":" (con `-F :`) y lo imprimo con `awk` que lo formateará con `printf` tomando como valores lo separado por las comas y eso lo ubicará en los placeholders `%s`.

El resultado sería algo por el estilo:

```
******************************* 
Nombre: nombre1                 
Teléfono: telefono1             
Edad: edad1                     
******************************* 
******************************* 
Nombre: nombre2                 
Teléfono: telefono2             
Edad: edad2                     
******************************* 
******************************* 
Nombre: nombre3                 
Teléfono: telefono3             
Edad: edad3                     
*******************************
```

O más cercano a lo que pides:

```
awk -F : 'BEGIN{
printf "*******************************\n"
}
{
printf "Nombre: %s\nTeléfono: %s\nEdad: %s\n*******************************\n",
$1, $2, $3
}' Agenda.txt
```

Puesto que la salida es:

```
*******************************
Nombre: nombre1
Teléfono: telefono1
Edad: edad1
*******************************
Nombre: nombre2
Teléfono: telefono2
Edad: edad2
*******************************
Nombre: nombre3
Teléfono: telefono3
Edad: edad3
*******************************
```

La diferencia entre este y el anterior es que aquí uso la sentencia de `BEGIN` para imprimir una primera línea de asteriscos para la parte superior.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace tu código es usar `cat` y `cut` para almacenar en una variable local.  El segundo comando `cut` sirve para sacar campos o simplificar ficheros, y los `-d` y `-f`, son argumentos que posee éste. El primero te delimita por : y el segundo te lista el primer campo. El lo mismo que usar el comando por ejemplo:

```
cat Agenda.txt | cut -d ":" -f 1 -s
```